# How to create Time Series using 2 Columns from a Pandas Data Frame and Group By

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, dataframe

I have a data frame (df) which looks like this:

```
Type    Date   Number
A       x      y
B       x      y
B       x      y
B       x      y
A       x      y
```

I want to group by the type and then still be able to keep the `Date` and `Number` columns.

My goal is to create separate pandas time series using the date and number data for type `A` and type `B` separately.

I tried the following:

`df.groupBy("Type").apply(lambda x: x.Date)`

The above function works but only returns one column.

`df.groupBy("Type").apply(lambda x: (x.Date, x.Number))`

The above function doesn't work and returns something that is not what I want at all.

Comment: I just answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33199052/how-to-calculate-rolling-mean-on-a-groupby-object-using-pandas/33200817#33200817