# How to calculate rolling mean on a GroupBy object using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to calculate rolling mean on a GroupBy object using Pandas?

My Code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("example.csv", parse_dates=['ds'])
df = df.set_index('ds')
grouped_df = df.groupby('city')
```

What grouped_df looks like:

[image]

I want calculate rolling mean on each of my groups in my GroupBy object using Pandas?

I tried pd.rolling_mean(grouped_df, 3).

Here is the error I get:

AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Edit: Do I use itergroups maybe and calculate rolling mean on each group on each group as I iterate through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the dates on your left column and all city values as separate columns.  One way to do this is set the index on `date` and `city`, and then unstack.  This is equivalent to a pivot table.  You can then perform your rolling mean in the usual fashion.

```
df = pd.read_csv("example.csv", parse_dates=['ds'])
df = df.set_index(['date', 'city']).unstack('city')
rm = pd.rolling_mean(df, 3)
```

I wouldn't recommend using a function, as the data for a given city can simply be returned as follows (`:` returns all rows):

```
df.loc[:, city]
```

Comment: How can I apply a function for each city or for each column in this "pivot table"?

Answer (score 2):

You could try iterating over the groups

```
In [39]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('aaaaabbbbbaaaccccbbbccc'),"bookings":range(1,24)})
In [40]: grouped = df.groupby('a')
In [41]: for group_name, group_df in grouped:
   ....:     print group_name
   ....:     print pd.rolling_mean(group_df['bookings'],3)
   ....:     
a
0           NaN
1           NaN
2      2.000000
3      3.000000
4      4.000000
10     6.666667
11     9.333333
12    12.000000
dtype: float64
b
5           NaN
6           NaN
7      7.000000
8      8.000000
9      9.000000
17    12.333333
18    15.666667
19    19.000000
dtype: float64
c
13   NaN
14   NaN
15    15
16    16
20    18
21    20
22    22
dtype: float64
```